# Make the mail body disabled in mailto js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, email, mailto

I'm building a shooping site where the customer is ablee to contact the seller with emails.

I dont want to use backend so I just use Mailto.
now, I have 2 questions:

1) Can I open the client mail with disabled field?
So that he wont be able to change the "To" field (for example)? 
I dont want to use "readonly" attribute because there are also fields that the user himself need to fill.

2) Can I send the mail from my code without the customer press "send"?

Thank you guys!

Comment: Try https://www.emailjs.com/ — Send Email Directly From JavaScript

Comment: @3rdthemagical ok I tryed it and it works fine, but how can I know if I exceed the limited email amount?

Comment: @3rdthemagical — That is **not** sending email directly from JavaScript. It is sending email through a third party web service to whom you have to give credentials to your email server. (And no doubt they are harvesting all the data you send through them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I open the client mail with disabled field?

No.

> Can I send the mail from my code without the customer press "send"?

No.

---

If you want to do that, then use server-side code to send the email. You might want to use a backend, but you need one. It can be one you run on your websites server or a third-party service.